# ElasticMapReduce: Is it possible to reuse already allocated EMR cluster?

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I specified --alive option in EMR CLI when I created a new cluster and I am wondering if it is possible to reuse the cluster in launching another job? I can't find any relevant option to get some kind of ID for the cluster? So does that mean that it is not possible to do so?